# Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path please check

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Why am I getting this error?

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>
> [2m2023-11-10 15:09:37.760[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
>
> [2m2023-11-10 15:09:37.795[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>
> [2m2023-11-10 15:09:38.193[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]

Screenshot of my project:

[image]

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.17</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.codeWithDurgesh.blog</groupId>
  <artifactId>blog-app-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>blog-app-api</name>
  <description>This is a backend apis for blogging</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

applicationContext:

[image]

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured Spring Boot to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as the driver class for your SQL database but you have not added the corresponding dependency to your application's `pom.xml` file.

Add the following to the `<dependencies>` section of your pom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```